# Windows based on Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux, windows, linux-kernel

Now this may come off as a dumb question, please bear with me as I am no expert in the subject. I am merely very curious.

I was merely wondering if it is possible to build a "windows-like" operating system that is based off the Linux Kernel.

What do I mean "Windows-Like"? 
For example, the file structure. In Linux, everything is represented as a file/folder. Now that "file" may be based off an entire hard disk or one folder in a hard disk. Whereas in windows Everything is neatly organised in terms of hard disk partitions and other connected devices. Files and folders are contained within partitions with the operating system being contained in a specific partition.

Also another thing is is that Linux for some reason rarely allows you to install applications on a particular directory, whereas with windows, you are able to install an application anywhere you choose. Only thing is that it will be added to the registry and some dependencies might get added to the C: drive. Now this a kernel level issue in Linux or is it possible to build the windows type of functionality using the Linux kernel itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The larger, fuzzier answer is "yes"; there is nothing in the kernel itself that precludes recreating a large portion of the Windows "user experience".

Having said that, there *are* some irreconcilable differences:

- Drivers work *very* differently with the Linux and Windows kernels.

  Since the Windows kernel API doesn't exist, drivers would need to be completely rewritten, either as Linux modules or as userspace wrappers.
- The Linux kernel does have some expectations regarding the filesystem containing it.

  Things such as modules and firmware have a specific location they're expected to be. And don't even get me started about what to do with `/proc` and `/sys`.

On the other hand there is quite a large amount of pre-existing work to build on:

- Wine has done a *lot* of work making a POSIX-compatible wrapper for the Windows API. It would require an appropriate libc, but there are few if any reasons that disallow a libc that is both POSIX- and WinAPI-compatible.
- ReactOS does have a Windowsesque interface that could be ported to the Linux kernel with some effort.

So it can be done, but whoever decides to undertake it would be in it for the long haul.

Comment: Plus, of course, most of those with the necessary skills would likely think it was a repulsive idea, for one reason or another. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.